# Access Auth::user() in route.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having a problem in accessing the Auth::user() in my route.php. So far here's what i've got:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    if(Auth::user()->role == "manager"){
        Route::get('/','ManagerController@index');
    }
    else if(Auth::user()->role == "rater"){
        Route::get('/','RaterController@index');
    }
});
```

It gives me this error "Trying to get property of non-object" whenever I try to use the Auth::user()->role

Comment: You'll need to make sure that `Auth::user()` is actually returning a valid object first (i.e the user is actually authenticated)

Answer (score 5):

Change your code to:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
            if (Auth::check()) {
                if(Auth::user()->role == "manager"){
                    Route::get('/','ManagerController@index');
                }
                else if(Auth::user()->role == "rater"){
                    Route::get('/','RaterController@index');
                }
            }
        });
```

Because if the current user has not logged in yet, he will not have a `role` so `Auth::user()` will return `null` and thus accessing `role` property is not possible. You need to check first if the user is logged in by using `if (Auth::check())`.

P.S. Checking the authentication inside the routes file is such a bad practice and should be handled inside a `controller`. Hope this helps.

Comment: When I add Auth::check it returns empty

Comment: @SydneyLoteria Are you logged in? Because if you are not logged in, it should return `empty`!

Comment: This is bad practice!! Not use the routes file to get access, you must do this in the controller

Comment: @Sangar82 I know it is a VERY bad practice, but it should still work. My answer Is just showing why the error happens and how to stop it from happening. But the checking should happen inside a controller as you said.

Comment: Auth::check will not working on route, any controller's constructor etc.. This is the limitation of laravel. This is why i leave laravel.

Comment: This is because when registering the routes, the middleware hasn't yet run so Auth::check() is always going to be false because Laravel hasn't authenticated the user at that point.

Comment: @ÄRÂmmãřŻąîñh ...you stopped using Laravel because it does basic things that are not just methodologically correct, but are intended from a security perspective?