# Use different controller for same route based on user role in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

What I want is I can use different controller for same route based on logged in user's role, so if user logged in with role of admin I want controller for given url is loaded from Admin namespace. I've done like this

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['install','auth']],function(){

    $role = \Auth::user()->role;
    switch ($role)
    {
        case 'admin':
            $prefix = 'Admin\\';
            break;
        case 'Foo':
            $prefix = 'Foo\\';
            break;

    }
    Route::resource('/foo',$prefix.'FooController');
    //.......
```

But is says that Auth::user() is null, is there another approach to do this?

Comment: using Auth::check() you can check if any user is logged in or not than by Auth::User()->role use can get user's role.make sure your use model extends Authenticatable.

Answer (score 1):

Try `auth()->user()` or include a specific `Auth` Module instead of `\Auth::user()` it might be that the interpreter is using a wrong `Auth` module since there are quite a few of these.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a redirect using middleware for either the admin or the 'Foo', just check the auth role and return a redirect, to the correct route.

```
class AdminOnly
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->role != 'admin'){
            return redirect('path/to/non/admin/route');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then define both routes in your routes file and use the middleware to redirect between them.

Comment: I don't want to do so much redirect in my application, what i need is using same url but different controller determined by user's role

Comment: There is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240330/access-authuser-in-route-php that has the same issue. It is not the best idea to do what you are trying to do. If the controllers are serving similar pages, then use a middleware, gates, guards to filter out content for non-admin users. If the content / pages you are serving are very different, they should probably have different routes